# Laravel Carbon Date Difference between two dates

Tags: php, laravel, php-carbon

I have a field in my DB which has a time stamp using moment js. The result is like so.

```
["2018-02-11 11:30:17","2018-02-11 11:20:17","2018-02-11 11:10:17"]
```

But when i return created_at colum from db the array is given like so:

```
[{"date":"2018-02-11 11:40:17.000000","timezone_type":3,"timezone":"Asia\/Karachi"},{"date":"2018-02-11 11:40:31.000000","timezone_type":3,"timezone":"Asia\/Karachi"},{"date":"2018-02-11 11:40:40.000000","timezone_type":3,"timezone":"Asia\/Karachi"}]
```

So how can i take two column dates in a format where carbon can understand? I want the "starttime" column to compare with "created_at". Is this achievable? Here is my code so far:

```
$cleanStart = Clean::pluck('starttime')->toArray();
$cleanFinish = Clean::pluck('created_at')->toArray();

$from = Carbon::parse($cleanStart);
$to = Carbon::parse($cleanFinish);
$diff_in_hours = $to->diffInHours($from);

return $diff_in_hours;
```

But it gives me an error:

```
Type error: DateTime::__construct() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given
```

Also how can i give the array to carbon.

So finally here is the thing i tried:

```
$cleanCollection = Clean::get(['starttime','created_at']);
        foreach($cleanCollection as $cleanObj){
            $startTime = Carbon::parse($cleanObj->starttime);
            $diff = $cleanObj->created_at->diffInseconds($startTime);
        }


       echo $diff;
```

But when ever i refresh the page, the value changes in seconds. and if another record is added, it adds up again.

Answer (score 2):

Pluck will give you an array of all of the start times from your result set which is why you're passing an array into `parse`. You're actually getting all of the start times and all of the created ats then trying to compare all to all, effectively.

You either need to get a single result,

Like

```
$clean = Clean::first();
$from = Carbon::parse($clean->starttime);
$to = Carbon::parse($clean->created_at);
$diff_in_hours = $to->diffInHours($from);
```

Or if you wanted it for each row you'd have to iterate over them and do much the same

```
Clean::all()->each(function ($clean) {
    $from = Carbon::parse($clean->starttime);
    $to = Carbon::parse($clean->created_at);
    $diff_in_hours = $to->diffInHours($from); // for this row
});
```

The other thing you could do is put an accessor on your Clean model to help you out with this

```
public function getDiffInHoursAttribute()
{
    $from = Carbon::parse($this->starttime);
    $to = Carbon::parse($this->created_at);
    return $to->diffInHours($from);
}
```

Then

```
echo Clean::first()->diffInHours;
```

Or

```
foreach(Clean::all() as $clean) {
    echo $clean->diffInHours;
}
```

Also, if you add the following to your model, Eloquent will automatically parse the strings into Carbon objects so you can skip the need for Carbon::parse() in your code

```
/**
 * The attributes that should be mutated to dates.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $dates = [
    'starttime'
];
```

Comment: +1 For the good explanation. I am sorry if i sound like a complete noob here but. I do get the right result from your first code. But the second one does not work. I cant get the results for each of the post separately as a list

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `protected $dates` to your  `Clean` model, like this:

```
/**
 * The attributes that should be mutated to dates.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $dates = [
    'created_at',
    'updated_at'
];
```

As you can read from the comments inside the code, put all of the columns that should be converted to dates inside, this will help you achieve date manipulations easier.

**EDIT 1:**

```
$start = new Carbon($cleanStart['date'], $cleanStart['timezone']);
$finish = new Carbon($cleanFinish['date'], $cleanFinish['timezone']);
```

Then you can compare like this:

```
var_dump($start->eq($finish)); //Is start date same as finish date
var_dump($start->ne($finish)); //Is start date not same as finish date
var_dump($start->gt($finish)); //Is start date greater than finish date
var_dump($start->gte($finish)); //Is start date greater than or equal to finish date
var_dump($start->lt($finish)); //Is start date less than finish date
var_dump($start->lte($finish)); //Is start date less than or equal to finish date
```

**EDIT 2:**

In order for the code underneath to work, you must initialize `$start` and `$finish` dates as in `EDIT 1`

```
$ago = $start->diffForHumans($finish, true); //2 days OR 3 weeks OR 1 hour
```

Comment: Thanks. But how do i resolve the problem. I have an array and i want to use it to tell the difference for each post.

Comment: You can create a Carbon dates from retrieved arrays and then you can do something like the above

Comment: what i want is to calculate the time elapsed from start to end. Eg: took 2100 seconds to write this post. There is a starttime column and created_at column. i want to use those two. Starttime being the start and created_at being the end